# Visual Studio with docker file support - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, dockerfile

I am new to docker. When I create an empty ASP.NET Core MVC project with linux docker support, Visual Studio generates this Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj DockerTest/
RUN dotnet restore DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/DockerTest
RUN dotnet build DockerTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish DockerTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

When I start PowerShell, change directory and run command

```
docker build .
```

i get error - no such file or directory.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  910.8kB
Step 1/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
 ---> bf6acba27669
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a48d00205739
Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93b2ba2ff3cc
Step 4/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
 ---> 9d32878ab9fe
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c5247716e9f
Step 6/16 : COPY DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj DockerTest/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder159418839/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is my fault. I should run this command from root project directory:

```
docker build -f "DockerTest/Dockerfile" .
```

Comment: How to change this in Azure DevOps pipelines?